# Android ArrayAdapter Error?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'am making a custom adapter for my **listView**  and I am getting this error "The constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int, int[]) is undefined"

here is the Adapter code:

```
class HeartlessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>
{
Context context;
int[] images;

HeartlessAdapter(Context c, int[] imgs)
{
    super(c, R.layout.imageview, imgs);  //this is the line that has the error
    this.context=c;
    this.images=imgs;
}

class MyViewHolder
{
    ImageView myImage;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
}
```

any tips on how to fix this error, thanks

Comment: in constructor, u only have 2 parameters i.e. Context c and int[] imgs. while in your super(), u have 3 items. remove R.layout.imageview. i dont find any point of keeping it there.

Comment: also describe what you want to do, so that i can better explain where to use R.layout.imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` and `Integer` are different in Java. You have to pass in `Integer[]` and not `int[]` as the 3rd argument to `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

Convert `int[] a` to `Integer[] b`:

```
Integer[] b = new Integer[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) b[i] = a[i];
```